# Unlink all connected objects at once

Tags: mesh, linked-data

If you have x number of linked objects sharing mesh data, how do you unlink all of them at once?  Right now I am clicking on one object at a time then pressing the number in the name field indicating the number of linked objects.  (EXAMPLE: If you have 62 objects sharing obdata and you want to unlink all of them at once to say apply loc/rot/scale values back to 1 via Ctrl+A, then relink to have them all connected again.) Maybe something like Alt + L, but that doesn't do it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > Object Data to select all visible objects that share the same data and then do <kbd>U</kbd> > Object and Data to make the selected objects single users.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > Object Data can then be used to link the selected objects together again after making any changes.